# 'platform method missing' and 'NoSuchMethod' errors in Google App Engine

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-admin

I have a Google App Engine server which is running Google Cloud Endpoints v1 and the Firebase Admin SDK.

I have been getting the errors below on the server when my mobile app accesses one of the cloud endpoints, specifically one which generates an HTTP request (unsure if this is related). However all other cloud endpoints accessed from the app are working correctly.

```
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil supportsUnsafeByteBufferOperations
WARNING: platform method missing - proto runtime falling back to safer methods: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.misc")
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil supportsUnsafeArrayOperations
WARNING: platform method missing - proto runtime falling back to safer methods: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.misc")
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil supportsUnsafeCopyMemory
WARNING: copyMemory is missing from platform - proto runtime falling back to safer methods.
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet init
INFO: SPI restricted: true
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod
SEVERE: exception occurred while calling backend method
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.checkNotDeleted(FirebaseApp.java:314)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getOptions(FirebaseApp.java:260)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.<init>(FirebaseAuth.java:74)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.<init>(FirebaseAuth.java:61)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.<init>(FirebaseAuth.java:52)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$FirebaseAuthService.<init>(FirebaseAuth.java:316)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(FirebaseAuth.java:98)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(FirebaseAuth.java:85)
```

Can anyone advise?

I have looked into similar reports which suggest that there are conflicting versions of the Guava dependency. When running `mvn dependency:tree`, it shows that there is only one Guava dependency (v20.0), which is included by the Firebase Admin SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what was going on, but fixed it with `mvn clean`.

Comment: Chances are your project was getting built with guava 19.0. Running `mvn clean` dropped the old artifacts from your `target/` directory, and rebuilt the project with guava 20.0